# Is it possible to order 2 Ubers at the same time?

Tags: applications

Using the Uber Android application, is it possible to book 2 Uber drivers at the same time?

Comment: Franck(ly), are you sure this is an *Android* specific question – and not rather a policy-related Uber question? Does Uber generally allow this? (as on SR, please include context ;) A good starting place might also be the [Uber help center](https://help.uber.com/) (yuck, do they only know the iOS app there?)

Comment: @Izzy Unsure, I didn't use the iPhone app. Perhaps Uber policy indeed :/

Comment: I'd say simply try it; if it works you'll know (and have to pay 2 drivers :)

Comment: And? Tried it? Wanna post an answer? I know you know that on SE sites, it's perfectly fine to [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17845/192154) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not seem possible to order 2 Ubers at the same time: requesting an Uber changes the application interface, making it impossible to request a second Uber.

[image]